# Trying to end my python code if certain conditions are met without any output

Tags: python, exit

I'm a *very* amateur programmer and was just messing around with making my own code outside of class. I made a simple game of sorts where random numbers meant to represent a series of dice rolls are generated, and a message is printed telling the user which "player" won. My issue is that I'm trying to print a message saying when two of more "players" tie without displaying the messages saying when individual "players" win or giving any output aside from the stuff I'm intentionally printing.

[My code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DMlG.png)

I attempted to use quit () and exit () but neither one stopped the extra messages.
I also imported sys and os and tried using sys.exit () and os.exit () functions, but both of those gave outputs on their own.

Comment: I think you're looking for `else:` and `elif:`.

Comment: It would appear that it did work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please include code as text, not as a link to a picture.

Comment: Now if you want to get better, try to think of ways to print the result message without having to individually list each case. Hint: as a starter, you might want to make a list of players: `players = ['Sam', ...]` and use a dict `roll = {}` to store the rolls: `for player in players: roll[player] = random...`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, that you wrap everything in a function and just return from that function, like:

```py
def RunGame():
    foo = 2;
    bar = 2;

    if foo == bar:
        print("FooBar")
    else:
        return

RunGame()
```